# Outlook DASL results to datagridview

Tags: vba, vb.net, outlook

I am trying to populate the DASL query results (Outlook Table) to a DataGridView in VB.NET Form using below code. Although Outlook table has results, data is not getting populated in the form - no error appears too. Any help please.

```
  Dim oT As Outlook.Table = eFolder.GetTable(strFilter)
  oT.Sort("[SentOn]", True)

  Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = oT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer, below is the code

```
        Dim RowCount As Integer = oT.GetRowCount
        Dim DtaSet(RowCount, 6) As String
        Dim VarArray As Array
        VarArray = oT.GetArray(RowCount)
        Dim myarr(RowCount) As mystructure

        For ix As Integer = 0 To RowCount - 1
            myarr(ix) = New mystructure With
            {
             .From = VarArray(ix, 0).ToString,
             .EmailTo = VarArray(ix, 1).ToString,
             .CC = VarArray(ix, 2).ToString,
             }
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = myarr
```

Continues as below:

```
    Structure mystructure
    Private mFrom As String
    Private mEmailTo As String
    Private mCC As String
Public Property From() As String
        Get
            Return mFrom
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mFrom = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property EmailTo() As String
        Get
            Return mEmailTo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mEmailTo = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property CC() As String
        Get
            Return mCC
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            mCC = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

[DataGridView.DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=netframework-4.7.2) has no knowledge of the `Outlook.Table` COM object. It is your responsibility to convert it into something that the control understands.

Comment: I have tried this code `VarArray = oT.GetArray(oT.GetRowCount)     
 Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = VarArray`.  
However, the datagrid is not being populated

Comment: From the link above: 

    The IList interface, including one-dimensional arrays.

    The IListSource interface, such as the DataTable and DataSet classes.

    The IBindingList interface, such as the BindingList<T> class.

    The IBindingListView interface, such as the BindingSource class.

Comment: You need to provide something that DataSource property understands.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook's tables and `DataSource` instances are entirely different entities. You need to create a binding object in the code on your own extracting the required fields from the `Items` collection.

The `DataGridView` class supports the standard Windows Forms data-binding model. This means the data source can be of any type that implements one of the following interfaces:

- The `IList` interface, including one-dimensional arrays.
- The `IListSource` interface, such as the DataTable and DataSet classes.
- The `IBindingList` interface, such as the BindingList class.
- The `IBindingListView` interface, such as the BindingSource class.

As you can see, Outlook doesn't provide anything for that.